# AucTeX PDF syncing in Emacs, multiple windows problem

Tags: emacs, auctex, forward-inverse-search

I have enabled `Tex-source-correlate-mode` with `synctex` as the syncing method. When I have a single Emacs window open, it works fine. But if I have multiple Emacs windows open, whenever I press Ctrl-left clik on the PDF document, the source file is opened in the most recent Emacs window (apparently). Is there a way to force the sync to occur to the original .tex file?

Comment: If you run Emacs twice or more, I can imagine that the pdfviewer has no possibility to find out, which Emacs is the right one. You know about C-x 5 2 to open more windows with Emacs, instead of starting it again?

Comment: Thanks, opening the other Emacs „OS Window” via the `make-frame` command (`SPC o f` in Doom Emacs) fixed the `synctex` behaviour. Emacs calls „OS Windows” frames and has windows within that frame.

Answer (score 4):

Run `M-x server-force-delete` in the most recent Emacs, and run `M-x server-start` in the Emacs that you want to open when clicking in the PDF document.

Comment: Do you mean to run 'M-x server-force-delete' just in the last instance, or every Emacs other than the original. Also, is there a more automatic way of doing it?

Comment: I said 'the most recent Emacs' because that is the instance of Emacs that you said opens when clicking. In general, you should delete the server in the 'wrong' window and start it in the window you want. I do not know a way to make it automatic. I also do not know if auctex starts the server automatically, in practice you should be able to just start the server in the desired window.

Comment: Thanks, I have have experimented some more, and your solution does not seem to work. Even though I kill the server, it still jumps to that window.

Comment: Why do you have multiple instances of Emacs?  Maybe one instance (possibly with multiple frames) will help?

Comment: After killing the server with `server-force-delete` in one instance you need to start it with `server-start` in another.

Comment: @mbrok, yes that is what I am force to do for now. Still, it is nice to have the option of having multiple Emacs windows open at the same time. This used to work when syncing was not officially supported by AucTeX, using the hacks added to .emacs.

Comment: @Sašo Živanović, no comibination of these commands that I have tried seem to have the desired effect. I even tried deleting the serves in every instance first and starting it in just one of them. It is still not very predictable which window will be picked to jump to.